# Microsoft grap: GetGroupFromIdS2SRequest. Workload MsGraph_DirectoryServices

Tags: windows, graph

I have aproject project in Java. When I run the project I got a error: GetGroupFromIdS2SRequest. Workload MsGraph_DirectoryServices, Someone would said me how to fix it?.

```
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().clientId("xxxx").clientSecret("yyyy").tenantId("zzzz").build();
        List<String> scope = new ArrayList<>();
        scope.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider( scope, clientSecretCredential);
        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider).buildClient();
        GroupCollectionPage groupCollectionPage = graphClient.groups().buildRequest().get();
        Group group = new Group();
        group.description = "Group with designated owner and members207";
        group.displayName = "Operations group207";
        LinkedList<String> groupTypesList = new LinkedList<String>();
        groupTypesList.add("Unified");
        group.groupTypes = groupTypesList;
        group.mailEnabled = false;
        group.mailNickname = "operations207";
        group.securityEnabled = true;           
        group.additionalDataManager().put("\"owners@odata.bind\"", new JsonPrimitive("[  \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/11111111\"]"));    
        String sIdGrupo = graphClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group).id;    
      Team team = new Team();
      TeamMemberSettings memberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings();
      memberSettings.allowCreateUpdateChannels = true;
      team.memberSettings = memberSettings;
      TeamMessagingSettings messagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings();
      messagingSettings.allowUserEditMessages = true;
      messagingSettings.allowUserDeleteMessages = true;
      team.messagingSettings = messagingSettings;
      TeamFunSettings funSettings = new TeamFunSettings();
      funSettings.allowGiphy = true;
      funSettings.giphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.STRICT;
      team.funSettings = funSettings;
      graphClient.groups(sIdGrupo).team().buildRequest().put(team);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before: Team team = new Team();, I added this line:

```
try {
    sleep(30000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```